# Дефисное написание сложных прилагательных

Tags: орфография, прилагательные

Как пишется прилагательное *"квазинаучно-технический"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как пишется прилагательное *"квазинаучно-технический"*?

Правильно: ***квази-научно-технический***.

См. [***"Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник" под ред. Лопатина:***](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80)

> **§ 152. Недопустимо слитное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть слова содержит дефис.** Слитное
>   написание должно заменяться дефисным, в результате чего возникают
>   написания с двумя дефисами. Например, следует писать:
>   *полу-конференц-зал, полу-социал-демократы, ультра-ура-патриот, радио-мюзик-холл, теле-пресс-конференция, теле-ток-шоу,
>   **анти-социал-демократический, лже-тред-юнионистский,
>   псевдо-историко-революционный**.*

Comment: Да, видимо, этот вариант верный. Мне вот тоже что-то подобное вспоминалось, но найти не смогла... вернее, у Лопатина и не пыталась, а в "Справочнике по литературной правке" этого, видимо не было...

Comment: Ничего удивительного, что не нашли. Такие вещи стали обсуждать относительно недавно - и только такие авторы, как Лопатин. А он, увы, большим авторитетом "в определенных кругах" не пользуется. Даже тогда, когда к нему явно надо прислушаться. Причина, в частности, - в нечеткости формулировок, вот как сейчас. Если почитаешь, так **недопустимо** вовсе, а ситуация-то тоньше. И не о всякой приставке речь идет - и не о всякой ситуации с ней.

Answer (score 1):

По аналогии с *научно-технический*: квазинаучно-технический. Наличие приставки *квази* не влияет на дефисное написание.

Пишутся через дефис прилагательные, образованные из двух или более основ слов, обозначающих равноправные понятия, напр.: научно-технический.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Alenka, выбор написания в подобных случаях зависит от смысла. Если "квази" (или другой подобный преффикс: псевдо, контр, ультра, инфра и проч.) относится только к первой части составного понятия, то и слитное написание первой части законно и регулируется общим правилом, о котором пишет Cерж.

Но это - великая редкость. В нормальном понимании "квази" относится ко всему понятию ("научно-технический" в нашем случае). Поэтому, чтобы избежать недоразумения, и используют другое, "двудефисное" написание, о чем говорят Лопатин и slava1947. Так что я в данном случае присоединяюсь к ним - с той маленькой оговоркой, что слитное написание возможно в редких случаях, о которых я сказал.